# How to draw grid by given four points in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

It is easy to draw a grid on a square if the square is not rotated. But for rotated squares it is difficult for me to grid it. I want to grid a square by given four points. for example the following four points:

A(-3,0), B (-2,5), C(-5,3), D(0,2).

Any suggest would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Those points do not form a square.

Comment: What is your Reasoning?

Comment: I drew them in a diagram and looked at it.

Comment: The grid command takes options just as any other, such as `[rotation=<angle>]`. Figure out the rotation of your rectangle, put that rotation into the grid rotation option, done. Example: `\tikz[rotate=30] \draw[step=1mm] (0,0) grid (2,2);`

Comment: There is no good way?

Comment: That is a perfectly good way. No fuss involved. What is your usual way? Care to edit an MWE into your question so that we can help you better?

Comment: I haven't said that, I've merely pointed out that your example points do not form a square (or even a rectangle or parallellogram for that matter).

Comment: I think C(-5,3) makes it into a square.

Comment: square or not, we want a grid. The `grid` command is the standard way, can be rotated, slanted (`xslant`/`yslant`) and undergo any arbitrary matrix-transformation. Even non-linear transformations are possible, as the pgf manual helpfully points out (section 17.7). There are other ways to draw grids (`axis` systems, `\foreach` statements…) but `grid` is by far the easiest one.

Comment: @Huang_d Well, yes, but if the corners are defined, then you need to calculate the rotation angle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility using the `calc` library and a loop.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,1);
\coordinate (C) at (2,4);
\coordinate (D) at (-1,3);


\foreach [evaluate=\i as \x using \i/10] \i in {0,...,10} 
{
  \draw ($(A)!\x!(B)$) -- ($(D)!\x!(C)$);
  \draw ($(A)!\x!(D)$) -- ($(B)!\x!(C)$);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Brute force, without `calc`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \t in {0,1,...,10}
  {
   \draw({-3+\t*(-5-(-3))/10},{0+\t*(3-0)/10})--({0+\t*(-5-(-3))/10},{2+\t*(3-0)/10});
   \draw({-3+\t*(0-(-3))/10},{0+\t*(2-0)/10})--({-5+\t*(3-0)/10},{3+\t*(2-0)/10});
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```